# Google maps in R

Tags: r, google-maps

I have the below data frame and I want to plot it with google maps as I already had an account and API with google, but I don't know-how and there are many resources that I lost in it. 
I got the (long and latit) by geocode() already as below

The variables are : `Program  Credits Univ Location  lon   lat`

Any advice?

```
     Program
2                Master's Programme in Data Science - Data Engineering
3                                       Data Science: Master programme
4                                    Data Science - Master's Programme
5                                    Data Science - Master's Programme
6                                     Master Programme in Data Science
8 Master's Programme in Data Science - Machine Learning and Statistics
  Credits                           Univ Location      lon      lat
2     120             Uppsala University  Uppsala 17.63893 59.85856
3     120             Dalarna University Borlänge 15.43397 60.48430
4     120           University of Skövde   Skövde 13.84612 58.39028
5      60           University of Skövde   Skövde 13.84612 58.39028
6      60 Luleå University of Technology    Luleå 22.15670 65.58482
8     120             Uppsala University  Uppsala 17.63893 59.85856
```

Comment: Hey @MohamedSalah, you are asking how to plot the data.frame with google maps and I think the answer below addresses this. I tried it, reproducible, and it's a good effort on the user's side. If you have other questions or more technical issues, please post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `leaflet` and plot the points over OpenStreetMap layer. With this package you do not need an API or a linked account.

```
# Packages
library(dplyr) # to use the pipe operator (magrittr can be used too)
library(leaflet) # acces to openstreetmap layer
library(htmltools) # label each point

# Data
data <-  structure(list(
    Univ.location = c( "Uppsala University  Uppsala",
       "Dalarna University Borlänge", "University of Skövde   Skövde", 
       "University of Skövde   Skövde", "University of Technology    Luleå", 
       "Uppsala University  Uppsala"),
    lon = c(17.63893, 15.43397, 13.84612, 
             13.84612, 22.1567, 17.63893),
    lat = c(59.85856, 60.4843, 58.39028, 
           58.39028, 65.58482, 59.85856)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

# Map


data %>% 
    leaflet() %>% 
    addTiles() %>% 
    addCircleMarkers( label = ~htmlEscape(Univ.location))
```

Here a useful [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/)

Comment: Thanks johan for your support,
but now I got a google key {has_google_key()  [1] TRUE} 
So, any way could I use it with google maps?